# Best way to send information from a client-side Ruby script to a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

**I would like to create entries in a Track (as in music) database in a Rails application by sending the track data information from a client-side Ruby script.**  I only need to create and destroy tracks from the script, I don't need to have any web interface, and I'm not worrying about authentication/authorization at the moment. **Could someone please walk me through (a) how to properly set up the Rails app (using Rails 2.3.8) and (b) how to send the data from a Ruby script?**

Here's the approach I have taken so far:

I have created a Track model and Tracks controller. Here is the Track controller code:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @track = Track.new(params[:track])
    respond_to do |format|  
      if track.save
        format.any(:xml, :json) { head :ok }
      else
        format.xml { render :xml => @track.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
        format.json { render :json => @track.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @track = Track.find(params[:id])  
    @track.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.any(:xml, :json) { head :ok }
    end
  end    

end
```

I have set up the routes as follows:

```
  map.resources :tracks, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

To send the information from the Ruby script, I have tried (1) using ActiveResource and (2) using net/http with the track information in xml format.  For the latter, I'm not sure how to make the post request with net/http and also I'm unclear on how to properly format the xml. For example, can I just use to_xml on a track object?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The Ruby script you are talking about, is that run on the same server instance that your rails application is running at, or is it run on a remote server?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear. No, it would be script that would running on any number of client computers (like a client desktop application that communicates with the Rails backend). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any particular problems with your API, or how you are going about scripting it with an HTTP client. However, to get it to fit to the RESTful standard, your `create` call should return the object as XML or JSON. You can, indeed, simply call  [to_xml](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_xml) or [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) on the `@track` object. These functions accept options to further control the output. For instance, if you wish to exclude some piece of data from your API, you can pass the `:except` option. See the docs linked for more info.

As for your script, I personally prefer [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) over ActiveResource - very simple, easy to understand, and doesn't require that you fit your API exactly to the ActiveResource way of doing things. [The examples](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples) are a good place to start, or have a look at the [Chargify gem](https://github.com/pengwynn/chargify/blob/master/lib/chargify/client.rb) to see a longer example. HTTParty simply takes a Hash and converts it to XML or JSON. You don't need to have a Track object in your script (unless you really want to). Your script would be something like this:

```
require 'httparty'

class TrackPoster
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://hostname.com'

  def self.create_track(artist, song)
    post('/tracks', :body => { 
      :track => { :artist => artist, :song => song }})
  end
end

TrackPoster.create_track('The Beatles', 'Let It Be')
```

This call will return the parsed XML/JSON as a hash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated! I will give this a try and either accept the answer or get back with any questions.

Comment: For others' reference, this answer was correct with two slight revisions: (1) "self.base_uri = 'http://hostname.com'" should actually be "base_uri 'http://hostname.com'" and (2) the post method in the create_track method should actually be "self.class.post" method instead. Otherwise, worked great!